# Intercept change issues in growth curve model in R

Tags: regression, lme4-nlme, expected-value, intercept, growth-mixture-model

I am currently analyzing data using a growth curve model, and I have one question that puzzles me. I wonder why the intercept values keep changing when I add random effects or higher-order terms to the model. Moreover, in some cases, an intercept from a growth curve analysis becomes negative, even though it is clearly positive in the graphs (there is no negative value in my graph at all) that I draw from raw data before analysis. The data has three groups as independent variables, three conditions, and one of them serves as the reference group, each through dummy coding. Consequently, I need to interpret the intercept values relative to the reference group, which makes it very confusing that the intercept values keep changing. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me understand why this is happening.

`m <- lmer(data ~ Group * (ot1 + ot2 + ot3) + (1 | Subject)`

[image: the graph from my raw data]

[image: when there are three polynomial time terms]

[image: when there are two polynomial time terms]

Comment: I am not sure what is confusing you.  The growth curve model (like many other models) is fitting the best curve to the data, given certain constraints and assumptions. Unless you somehow constrain the intercept to be non-negative, then it can be.

YOU may know that a negative intercept is silly, but you are human. As Douglas Hofstadter put it, many years ago "Computers are logical but not reasonable, people are reasonable but not logical" (he was not talking about statistics but it applies here).

Comment: For your reference, I added my raw data graph. I still do not understand how these intercepts in the graph could be totally different from the intercepts of the results. I would very much appreciate it if you can help me.